# Return sourceBranch from a merge with master

Tags: azure-devops

I have a release pipeline. This pipeline has a stage configured to trigger on all branches except master. When a merge is triggered not with master, it will deploy the app in a Azure storage account.

I've also have a trigger for the master branch. This release gets triggered when there's a merge with master. When this happens I want to remove the previously created Azure storage account.

The problem is that when there's a merge with master there's no connection to the original merge request since the merge to master is it's own thing.

Is there any method to retrieve the build id/branch name of a merge request based on a new merge with master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any method to retrieve the build id/branch name of a merge request based on a new merge with master?

You can use Rest Api to achieve this requirement, please check [Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests By Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests%20by%20project?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Create request with parameter `searchCriteria.targetRefName`, it will search for pull requests into this branch. In the response, a `sourceRefName` can be found with the source branch name as its value.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted since I don't have acces to `targetRefName` but through `lastMergeCommit` I can find the required pull request!